# How to parse by Spring a name of a variable (key, but not value) from yaml when its name is changing?

Tags: spring, parsing, properties, micronaut

I have a yaml file with a structure

```
section:
  subsections:
    subsectionName1:
      param1: value1
      param2: value2   
    subsectionName2:
      param1: value1
      param2: value2
```

I need to parse these properties as `List<CustomClass>`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "section.subsections")
@Configuration
public class CustomClass {
  
  private final String subsectionName; //the problem is there
  private String param1;
  private String param2;

//Constructors, getters, setters
```

How can I do this in Spring?

I see that this works in Micronaut this way:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Context;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.EachProperty;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Parameter;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Context
@EachProperty("section.subsections")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CustomClass {
  
  private final String subsectionName;
  private String param1;
  private String param2;
 
  public CustomClass(@Parameter String subsectionName) {
    this.subsectionName = subsectionName;
  }
//getters, setters...
```

But I didn't manage to find something similar to `io.micronaut.context.annotation.Parameter` in Spring.

I need this to use the shared util class which accepts List as a parameter.

Are there any ideas on how to do this?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try something like that :

```
section:   
  subsections:
     subsectionName1: value1,value2
```

And in your code you need to parse this using ***@Value*** annotation and ***split*** function of Strings

```
@Value("#{'${section.subsections:}'.split(',')}") 
Set<String> subsections
```

In that case I use set, but you cant use list if you allow repeated values.

Comment: I think the yaml you show there is inconsistent with the structure of the yaml that the question is asking about.